# iOS: setUserInteractionEnabled with performSelector does not work on 64 bit

Tags: ios, 64-bit, user-interaction, performselector

If you try

```
 [self.view performSelector:@selector(setUserInteractionEnabled:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] afterDelay:2];
```

on the **64 bit** iPhone **(even on the simulator)** user interaction will be disabled. Regardless of any previous state.

This line works on **32 bit** iPhones though.

**Is this a bug in the OS? Am I missing something?**

Comment: Try @(1l), I'd expect the glue layer to cope with the data type translations, but maybe it's not so good :)

Comment: Thanks, it does work this way :) I've opted to use Martin's solution, but this is an interesting way nonetheless. What's with the @(1l)? I might be a big noob, but I don't remember seeing this kind of syntax for representing a BOOL.

Comment: @( X ) makes an NSNumber of a type appropriate for X.  1l is a constant long value of 1.  Combined it will result in [NSNumber numberWithLong:1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setUserInteractionEnabled:` expects a `BOOL` parameter but you are sending it a `NSNumber`. Your code worked just by chance in the 32-bit environment, but

```
 [self.view performSelector:@selector(setUserInteractionEnabled:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] afterDelay:2];
```

does not reset the property to `NO` even on 32-bit (when I tested it), so it does
not really work.

The easiest method to solve this problem is to use GCD:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, first param is not NSNumber, but BOOL. 
Just refactor it to:

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
});
```